# About Azure Affinity Group Performance

Tags: azure

If a "Cloud Service" and a "Storage" in same Affinity Group, will it performance better? Or as same as in same datacenter?

I ask this because I feel the "Cloud Service" and "Storage" in same Affinity Group is faster, and I get more network error(timeout) for storage in same data center (US South), for same PartitionKey/RowKey query.

So, if there has performance difference, how can I change a "storage" Affinity Group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the following blog post from Neil which explains Affinity Group in more details: http://convective.wordpress.com/2012/06/10/affinity-groups-in-windows-azure/. To paraphrase from the blog post, essentially an Affinity Group provides higher degree of co-location of your services within a data center.

To answer your 2nd question, once you have created a storage account with either the location or affinity group parameter, you can't change it later on. You would need to delete that storage account and recreate it. Please note that depending on the data you have in your storage account, it may take a while to delete that storage account. While a storage account is being "Deleted", you will not be able to create another storage account with the same name.

Comment: There's also a good wiki on TechNet: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7916.importance-of-windows-azure-affinity-groups.aspx